# Атрибут data html

Tags: html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каждый блок имеет атрибут `data-dep-id`, по плику на `edit` открывается попап, в котором я добавляю праздники. По клику на кнопку save  считываю атрибут у попапа `data-dep-id` и передаю его в запрос, но почему-то передается одно и то же значение первого открытого попапа.

```
$('.holidays-box').on('click', '.save-this-row', function(){
        var btn = $(this);
        var parentItem = btn.parents('.item');


        console.log(btn.parents('.holidays-box').data('dep-id'));
}


<!-- HOLIDAYS FORM TEMPLATE -->
    <script id="holidaysFormTpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
        <form action=""  class="tr for-clone item active" data-hol-id="{{:id}}">
            <div class="td parent">
                <div class="wrapp-input  edit v_name">
                    <input type="text" class="input-val" name="name" placeholder="Holiday" value="{{:name}}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="td parent">
                <div class="wrapp-input  edit">
                    <input type="text" id="choose_date" name="start_date" value="{{:start_date}}" class="date-pick" placeholder="Choose date">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="td right-align">
                <a href="#" class="btn waves-effect waves-light ml-10 small  save-this-row add-holiday">Save it</a>
            </div>
            <div class="td right-align">
                <a href="#" class="trash-ico "><span class="ico icon-trash "></span></a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </script>

<!-- HOLIDAYS FORM -->
<div id="modal-forgot" class="modal-forgot modal styled1 form-dynamic">           
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Public holidays</h4>
      <a href="#" class="modal-action modal-close btn_close"><i class="icon-close"></i></a>
      <div class="parent-form holidays-box">
        <div class="display-table">
            <div class="thead">
                <div class="tr">
                    <div class="th">HOLIDAY NAME</div>
                    <div class="th">PERIOD / DATE</div>
                    <div class="th">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="th">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tbody">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-foot">
            <button type="button" data-where='#form2 .tbody' class="btn waves-effect waves-block w-auto add-hol">Add New Holiday</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->   
</div><!-- /.modal-forgot --
```

>

EDIT кнопка

```
//GET HOLIDAYS
    $('#dep-box').on('click', '.show-holidays', function(){
        var btn = $(this);
        var depId = btn.parents('form').data('dep-id');

        $.ajax({
            url : '/settings/get_holidays',
            method  : 'POST',
            dataType    : 'json',
            data : { id : depId },
            success: function(data){
                var holidaysForm = $('#holidaysFormTpl').render(data);
                $('.holidays-box .display-table .tbody').html(holidaysForm);
                $('.holidays-box').attr('data-dep-id', depId);
                initializeDtepicker2();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Картинки - это, конечно, классно. Но мы же здесь все профессионалы - добавьте в вопрос html.

Comment: подправил вопрос

Comment: А попап какой? Bootstrap? или что? покажите также код кнопки edit

Comment: Материалайзовский попап!

Answer (score 1):

Вместо `$('#dep-box').on('click', '.show-holidays', function(){` попробуйте `$('div #dep-box').on('click', '.show-holidays', function(){`

Comment: А в чем разница собственно? Обращение к тому же блоку.Тут дело не в селекторах,а в том что data хранит значение первого открытого попапа,если использую attr вместо data то все хорошо.Видимо я не совсем понимаю до конца как data работает,вот и хочу чтобы подсказали!